# CKModifyRecordsOperation modifyRecordsCompletionBlock not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, cloudkit, ckmodifyrecordsoperation

I'm using `CKModifyRecordsOperation` to save a set of records and if I have internet connection all works well and completion block is being called. But when I don't have connection the completion block is not being called and I don't get any information that my operations failed.

I'm using the following code in completion block

```
modifyOperations.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = ^(NSArray *savedRecords, NSArray *deletedRecordIDs, NSError *error)
{
    if(error){
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }

    item.creatorRecordId = record.recordID;
};
```

and then I'm performing operation using

```
[self.publicDB addOperation:modifyOperations];
```

Any ideas how can I get an information if the operation failed for example in the case where there is no internet connection?

Comment: I've been dealing with this lately. If there is no Internet, the operation doesn't fail. It just waits. When your Internet connection returns, the operation will complete. One option (that I implemented) was to do a Reachability check before adding the operation to the database.

Comment: Yeah, I've been thinking about it too. But there can be a problem with this solution if the connection drops just after you checked for reachability and before performing operation... I've been thinking about implementing timer and then after some time check for reachability if the operation doesn't fire. But then again there is a question what this time should be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CloudKit operations have their `qualityOfService` property set to `NSQualityOfServiceUtility` by default.

Operations that use `NSQualityOfServiceUtility` or `NSQualityOfServiceBackground` may be marked as using [discretionary network requests](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLSessionConfiguration/discretionary). The system can hold discretionary network requests if network connectivity is poor, so you might not get a response from the server until conditions improve and the system sends the request.

If you'd like your request to be sent immediately in all cases, set `CKOperation.qualityOfService` to `NSQualityOfServiceUserInitiated` or `NSQualityOfServiceUserInteractive`.