# How to resolve CloudKit functionality inconsistency between devices

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I've integrated CloudKit into my iOS app and I'm encountering functionality inconsistency between devices.

One of my users has an iPod 5th Gen and an iPhone 6. If they use the iPod everything works as expected. However if they use the iPhone 6 they can only receive data and notifications, they can't make changes of their own. When the iPhone attempts to make changes to the iCloud public database I receive no errors and changes are made locally, they just never make it to the server (everything appears to work, it just doesn't).

Given that the user can use the iPod successfully but the same iCloud account only receives data on the iPhone suggests to me that this might be a permissions or settings issue.

### I've checked:

- User is logged into iCloud
- iCloud drive is on
- The app appears enabled in the iCloud Drive menu in settings
- The app appears enabled under the "Look Me Up By Email" menu

### Other details:

- The app is available through TestFlight
- The app is using the production container (required for TestFlight)

I don't know what code to supply because the app functions as expected on other devices but let me know what could help. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm assuming the iPhone can see changes made by the iPod? By "changes are made locally" do you mean that the iPhone can fetch the change it just made back out of the public database? Do you see these records in the iCloud Dashboard? How are you fetching these records- with a query operation or fetching by record ID? Records may not show up in queries to other clients for a bit of time while they are indexed, but they'll always be fetch able by record ID.

Comment: The iPhone can see changes. The completion handler for my CKModifyRecordsOperation method saves changes to the local data model when successful. The changes and records created on the iPhone do not appear in the iCloud Dashboard. I use both query operations and single record fetches depending on context. The iPhone has no issue fetching records, I only have issues creating or modifying records. The confusing part to me is my modify operations return no errors and execute the completion handlers as if they succeeded. Changes just don't make it to the iCloud servers. Thanks for your time.

Comment: That's very odd that changes from the phone aren't showing up in the public database. Are you sure you're not getting an error back either in the perRecordCompletionBlock or modifyRecordsCompletionBlock? Is there any chance the iPhone is jailbroken?

Comment: Also, if you can get the console log from this user's iPhone when the record save happens it might have a clue about what's happening.

Comment: Nope, no errors. My errors are displayed as uialertviews for testing, even if they're being handled properly I display the alert view and log it just to have a record. Phone's not jailbroken. I'll continue testing and see if I'm missing something, but I'm pretty stumped. I've actually reviewed a couple of you're other cloudkit relate answers and I'm going to try a couple of those ideas. I'm going to look at qualityOfService and review my completion handlers, I could have an error in there. Thanks again.

Comment: If your completion handler is getting called and you never received an error for this record then it's probably worth filing a radar about this. You can have your user follow the instructions at https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/ios/icloud/#icloud-drive to grab CloudKit logs, then attach them to a new bug at http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, this was resolved yesterday. I'll provide an answer for anyone else interested below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved by changing my modify operations qualityOfService property to .UserInitiated.

After I reviewed the completion handler for my CKModifyRecordsOperation I realized that I was saving data necessary for local functionality regardless of whether the completion handler received an error or not (and incidentally, whether it was executed or not). So when it appeared to me that my operation was being run and returning no errors, it actually wasn't being run at all. Changing the qualityOfService appears to have resolved this.

[Answer that led to the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34277850/4473451/)